STM32F03C8T6 (Bluepill) problem when work with JSON using cJSON library
I am currently working with a bluepill STM32 board to stream JSON data to my computer, but it always give me null return. I am trying any method and tutorial provided in internet but it gives nothing.
This is my code to stream JSON data to my PC.
When I try to debug it, it brings me that cJSON_Print fail to allocate buffer memory. Has anyone had and already solved the same problem or have any other suggestion?

char* adxl_getConfig(){
    uint8_t data[22];
    data[0] = adxl_read(ADXL_DEVID);
    data[1] = adxl_read(ADXL_THRESH_TAP);
    data[2] = adxl_read(ADXL_OFFZ);
    data[3] = adxl_read(ADXL_DUR);
    data[4] = adxl_read(ADXL_LATENT);
    data[5] = adxl_read(ADXL_WINDOW);
    data[6] = adxl_read(ADXL_THRESH_ACT);
    data[7] = adxl_read(ADXL_THRESH_INACT);
    data[8] = adxl_read(ADXL_TIME_INAT);
    data[9] = adxl_read(ADXL_ACT_INACT_CTL);
    data[10] = adxl_read(ADXL_THRESH_FF);
    data[11] = adxl_read(ADXL_TIME_FF);
    data[12] = adxl_read(ADXL_TAP_AXES);
    data[13] = adxl_read(ADXL_TAP_STATUS);
    data[14] = adxl_read(ADXL_BW_RATE);
    data[15] = adxl_read(ADXL_POWER_CTL);
    data[16] = adxl_read(ADXL_INT_ENABLE);
    data[17] = adxl_read(ADXL_INT_MAP); 
    data[18] = adxl_read(ADXL_INT_SOURCE);
    data[19] = adxl_read(ADXL_DATA_FORMAT);
    data[20] = adxl_read(ADXL_FIFO_CTL);
    data[21] = adxl_read(ADXL_FIFO_STATUS);
    
    const char* name[22] = {
    "devId",
    "TreshTap",
    "OFFSETZ",
    "DUR",
    "Latent",
    "Window",
    "TrehAct",
    "TreshInact",
    "TimeInat",
    "InatCTL",
    "TreshFF",
    "TimeFF",
    "TapAxes",
    "TapStatus",
    "BwRate",
    "PowerCTL",
    "IntEnable",
    "IntMap",
    "IntSource",
    "DataFormat",
    "FifoCTL",
    "FifoStat" };
    
    cJSON *json = cJSON_CreateObject();
    if (json == NULL) {
        return NULL; 
  }
    int index;
    for(index = 0 ; index < sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) ; index++){
        char hexVal[5];
        snprintf(hexVal, sizeof(hexVal), "%04X", data[index]);
        cJSON_AddStringToObject(json, name[index], hexVal);
    }
    
    char* jsonString = cJSON_Print(json);
    if(json == NULL){
        return "json print fail";
    }
    cJSON_Delete(json);
    return jsonString;
}


The problem may be how you use the library. If it takes too much memory then you don't have enough memory. Do trace why it fails and do check how much memory you already use and how much is free.

The MCU mentioned in the title does not exist. Did you mean STM32F103C8T6 or STM32F030C8T6?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's likely that hooks->allocate is trying to malloc memory from the system heap. Have you configured your project appropriately to have a heap at all? How much memory have you allocated to the heap?

thanks guys this problem solved by increasing heap min size using cubeMX, i change it from 200 to 400 and delete memory allocated every end of function call using free() dan cJSON_delete()
